# How to change item position on queue?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mongodb, nosql

My project on c#, I have mongodb collection, I use it for queue. For example I have some items on this queue, and i want change position of my items:

`[{id: 1, qPosition: 1}, {id: 2, qPosition: 2}]`

`[{id: 1, qPosition: 2}, {id: 2, qPosition: 1}]` And how do auto increment field for document, like a SQL DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that the contents of the database update
Use this command

```
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;
```

and

```
var info_id = Query.EQ("_id", "1");
IMongoUpdate info_up = Update.Set("qPosition","2");
cinfo.Update(info_id, info_up);

var info_id = Query.EQ("_id", "2");
IMongoUpdate info_up = Update.Set("qPosition","1");
cinfo.Update(info_id, info_up);
```

other Way

```
    var info_id1 = Query.EQ("_id", "1");
    IMongoUpdate info_up2 = Update.Set("qPosition","2");
    var info_id2 = Query.EQ("_id", "2");
    IMongoUpdate info_up2 = Update.Set("qPosition","1");

    cinfo.Update(info_id1, info_up1).Update(info_id2, info_up2);
```

in top way send one request to db

Comment: thx, but it very simple, maybe you know how do this more pretty, with out two calls to db.

Comment: Question: how do increment field like a SQL db, on mongo document?

Comment: you can check [link](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/) to auto increment field in mongodb @aleksandr-repetskyi